# jQuery Image Upload - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I use jQuery Image upload like this http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

I get the thumbnail and after clicking the upload button I get the progress bar, but then get 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character'

view page

```
</body>
</html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
<!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
<style type="text/css">body {padding-top: 80px;}</style>
<meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bar and preview images for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (Google App Engine, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload', array('id'=>'fileupload')); ?>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="span16 fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="progressbar fileupload-progressbar fade"><div style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                <span class="btn success fileinput-button">
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn primary start">Start upload</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn info cancel">Cancel upload</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn danger delete">Delete selected</button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span16">
                <table class="zebra-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<!-- gallery-loader is the loading animation container -->
<div id="gallery-loader"></div>
<!-- gallery-modal is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
<div id="gallery-modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn primary next">Next</a>
        <a class="btn info prev">Previous</a>
        <a class="btn success download" target="_blank">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var fileUploadErrors = {
    maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
    minFileSize: 'File is too small',
    acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
    maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
    uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
    emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
};

</script>
<script id="template-upload" type="text/html">
{% for (var i=0, files=o.files, l=files.length, file=files[0]; i<l; file=files[++i]) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name">{%=file.name%}</td>
        <td class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label important">Error</span> {%=fileUploadErrors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td class="progress"><div class="progressbar"><div style="width:0%;"></div></div></td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}<button class="btn primary">Start</button>{% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}<button class="btn info">Cancel</button>{% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script id="template-download" type="text/html">
{% for (var i=0, files=o.files, l=files.length, file=files[0]; i<l; file=files[++i]) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name">{%=file.name%}</td>
            <td class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label important">Error</span> {%=fileUploadErrors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">Delete</button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates and Load Image plugins are included for the FileUpload user interface -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Modal and Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-modal.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/application.js"></script>
<!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->


</body> 
</html>
```

controller page:

```
class upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));



    }

    function index()
    {    
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; // server directory
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; // by extension, will check for whether it is an image
        $config['max_size']    = '1000'; // in kb
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->library('Multi_upload');

        $files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();

        if ( ! $files )        
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('index', $error);
        }    
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $files);
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }    
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Check: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/517 Seems like a common problem.

Comment: Thanks, but where should I put this code from last post? When I put in __construct() I get error: Message: Undefined property: upload::$_request

Comment: At github, the post mentions putting the code right at the beginning of the action - so I guess in your do_upload function. Not able test myself right now, sorry =/

Comment: Is your controller file encoded in UTF-8 without BOM? I've had that extra byte at the beginning mess up many a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error even when the files were uploading successfully. The issue I came across was what I was returning. More info can be found here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup and the section labelled **Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) with a custom server-side upload handler**

so it basically says: *"Note that the response should always be a JSON object containing a files array even if only one file is uploaded."* You should still pass a files array back even if you get a server side error.

Here is an example of my Upload function (the keys part are the "echo json_encode"):

```
function upload_file($component_files_id = null,$thumb_width = 400)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = ($component_files_id) ? './documents/component_files/'.$component_files_id : './documents/image_uploads';
    if (!file_exists($config['upload_path']))
        @mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, true);

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|doc|docx|docm|odt|xls|xlsx|xlsm|ods|csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000'; #in KB
    $config['max_width']  = '5000';
    $config['max_height']  = '5000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors('','');

        if(is_ajax()){
            $file['error'] = $error;
            echo json_encode(array('files'=>array($file)));
        }
        else
            set_message($error,'error',true);
    }
    else
    {
        $file = $this->upload->data();
        $file['is_image'] =  ($file['is_image'] == '1') ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
        $file['updated_by'] = get_user('user_id');
        $file['created_by'] = get_user('user_id');
        if($component_files_id)
            $file['component_files_id'] = $component_files_id;
        //save the file details to the database
        $file_id = $this->page_model->save_file($file); 
        if($file['is_image'] == 'TRUE'){    
            $thumb_width = ($component_files_id) ? 290 : $thumb_width; 
            $this->_create_thumbnail($file_id,$thumb_width);
        }
        //set the data for the json array   
        $info->id = $file_id;
        $info->name = $file['file_name'];
        $info->size = $file['file_size'];
        $info->type = $file['file_type'];
        if($file['is_image'] == 'TRUE'){
            $info->url =    base_url().'files/image/'.$file_id;
            $info->thumbnail_url = base_url().'files/image/'.$file_id.'/thumb';
        }
        else{
            $info->url =    base_url().'files/download/'.$file_id;
            $info->thumbnail_url = base_url().'images/document-icon.png';               
        }               

        $info->delete_url = base_url().'files/delete_document/'.$file_id;
        $info->delete_type = 'DELETE';  
        $files['files'] = array($info);
        header('Content-type: text/html');
        echo json_encode($files);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to start, none of the script files referenced at the bottom of the your view exist:

1. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js
2. http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js
3. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.fileupload.js
4. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js
5. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js
6. http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/application.js

This would show up in your web console. Try to keep an eye on it at all times.

Head over to [This GitHub Page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload,---Multi-file-upload-with-CodeIgniter) and follow the directions to get this up-and-running w/ CodeIgniter.